# Why doesn't Scala's implicit class work when one of the type parameters should be Nothing?

Tags: scala, polymorphism, scala-2.10, enrich-my-library

**Update:** I modified the example so that can be compiled and tested.

I have an implicit class that defines an enrichment method:

```
case class Pipe[-I,+O,+R](f: I => (O, R));

object Pipe {
  // The problematic implicit class:
  implicit class PipeEnrich[I,O,R](val pipe: Pipe[I,O,R]) extends AnyVal {
    def >->[X](that: Pipe[O,X,R]): Pipe[I,X,R] = Pipe.fuse(pipe, that);
    def <-<[X](that: Pipe[X,I,R]): Pipe[X,O,R] = Pipe.fuse(that, pipe);
  }

  def fuse[I,O,X,R](i: Pipe[I,O,R], o: Pipe[O,X,R]): Pipe[I,X,R] = null;

  // Example that works:
  val p1: Pipe[Int,Int,String] = Pipe((x: Int) => (x, ""));
  val q1: Pipe[Int,Int,String] = p1 >-> p1;

  // Example that does not, just because R = Nothing:
  val p2: Pipe[Int,Int,Nothing] = Pipe((x: Int) => (x, throw new Exception));
  val q2: Pipe[Int,Int,String] = p2 >-> p2;
}
```

The problem is it doesn't work when `R` is `Nothing` in the second example. It results in an compiler error: In such a case, I get the following compiler error:

> ```
> Pipe.scala:19: error: type mismatch;
>  found   : Pipe[Int,Int,R]
>  required: Pipe[Int,Int,String]
>   val q2: Pipe[Int,Int,String] = p2 >-> p2;
> ```

**Why does this happen?**

---

I managed to solve it by creating a separate implicit class for that case:

```
trait Fuse[I,O,R] extends Any {
  def >->[X](that: Pipe[O,X,R])(implicit finalizer: Finalizer): Pipe[I,X,R];
}

protected trait FuseImpl[I,O,R] extends Any with Fuse[I,O,R] {
  def pipe: Pipe[I,O,R];
  def >->[X](that: Pipe[O,X,R]) = Pipe.fuse(pipe, that);
  def <-<[X](that: Pipe[X,I,R]) = Pipe.fuse(that, pipe);
}

implicit class PipeEnrich[I,O,R](val pipe: Pipe[I,O,R])
  extends AnyVal with FuseImpl[I,O,R];
implicit class PipeEnrichNothing[I,O](val pipe: Pipe[I,O,Nothing])
  extends AnyVal with FuseImpl[I,O,Nothing];
```

But can I rely on Scala's behavior in the future, that it will not consider `Nothing` as an option for `R`? If that changes in the future, the code will stop working because I'll have two different applicable implicits.

Comment: Shouldn't `Pipe.fuse(this, that)` be rather `Pipe.fuse(pipe, that)` ?

Comment: And by the way, what is `B`? It doesn't seem to be declared anywhere.

Comment: Could you please show the signature of `Pipe.fuse`?

Comment: @ghik I corrected the typos you mentioned and added a signature for `Pipe.fuse`. Actually, I have two methods, one is `>->` and the other is `<-<` for `fuse(pipe, that)`, I added the other one too. But it isn't really relevant to the problem with `Nothing`/`R`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... You haven't shown all your code, and the code you did show has some confusing inconsistencies. So this is going to be a wild guess. I suspect your problem is that `Pipe` is invariant in its type parameter `R`. Here's my simplified example:

```
case class Test[A](a: A)

object Test {
  implicit class TestOps[A](val lhs: Test[A]) extends AnyVal {
    def >->(rhs: Test[A]): Test[A] = ???
  }

  def test {
    def lhs = Test(???)
    def rhs = Test(???)
    lhs >-> rhs
  }
}
```

The compile error I get from this code is:

```
value >-> is not a member of Test[Nothing]
     lhs >-> rhs
         ^
```

... which I admit is not the same as the error you posted. But I don't entirely trust what you posted, so I'm going to keep going! The fix for this is to make `Test` covariant in its type parameter `A`:

```
case class Test[+A](a: A)
```

I honestly don't understand why the compile error happens to begin with. It seems like the compiler doesn't want to unify `A =:= Nothing` in the conversion to `TestOps`, but I don't see why not. Nevertheless, `Test` should be covariant in `A` anyways, and I'm guessing your `Pipe` class should likewise be covariant in `R`.

## Edit

I just spent a few minutes looking through the [Scala bug list](https://issues.scala-lang.org) and found several possibly related issues: [SI-1570](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-1570), [SI-4509](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4509), [SI-4982](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4982) and [SI-5505](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5505). I don't really know any details, but it sounds like `Nothing` is treated specially and shouldn't be. Paul and Adriaan would be the guys to ask...

Comment: It's defined as `trait Pipe[-I,+O,+R]`. I'll update the code tomorrow so that it's complete and can be compiled.

Comment: I just realized this stuff is all in your `scala-conduit` repo. I'm just going to clone that and see what I can figure out...

Comment: Just sent you a pull request :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. However, while adding co(ntra)variance to the type solves the problem, it doesn't answer the question: why the `implicit class` works for every type but `Nothing`?

Comment: Variance+inference+implicit bug, as far as I can tell. Works without variance annotations if you explicitly write: `FlatMap((1L to 1000000L).toSource >-> foldF[Long,Long](_ + _, 0L)) >-> chkInterrupted` in your `TestUtil`.