# Implicit error when trying to implement the `Absurd` typeclass

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit, bottom-type

I'm trying to implement the [`Absurd` typeclass (as seen in Haskell's Data.Boring library)](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/boring-0.1.3/docs/Data-Boring.html#t:Absurd) in Scala.

I'm able to define an `Absurd` instance for `Nothing`.
Unfortunately, when I try to define an absurd instance for `Either`, I get a missing implicit error

```scala
sealed trait Absurd[A] {
    def absurd[X](a: A): X
}

object Absurd {
  def apply[A: Absurd, B](a: A):B = implicitly[Absurd[A]].absurd[B](a)

  implicit val absurdForNothing: Absurd[Nothing] = new Absurd[Nothing]{
    override def absurd[X](a: Nothing): X = a
  }

  implicit def absurdForEither[A: Absurd, B: Absurd]: Absurd[Either[A, B]] = new Absurd[Either[A, B]]{
    override def absurd[X](a: Either[A,B]): X = a match {
      case Left(a) => Absurd[A, X](a)
      case Right(b) => Absurd[B, X](b)
    }
  }
}
```

This compiles:

```scala
implicitly[Absurd[Nothing]]
```

This fails to compile:

```scala
implicitly[Absurd[Either[Nothing, Nothing]]]
```

I'm using Scala Version "2.13.2".

It is possibly intersting to note, that the following, very similar code (which doesn't involve `Nothing`), does compile:

```scala
trait SomeTypeclass[A]
case class SomeInstance()

object SomeTypeclass {
  implicit val someTypeclassForSomeInstance: SomeTypeclass[SomeInstance] = new SomeTypeclass[SomeInstance] {}

  implicit def someTypeclassForEither[A: SomeTypeclass, B: SomeTypeclass]: SomeTypeclass[Either[A, B]] = new SomeTypeclass[Either[A, B]] {}
}
object SomeApplicationCode {
  implicitly[SomeTypeclass[Either[SomeInstance, SomeInstance]]]
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61951621/failed-implicit-resolution-for-nothing-with
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15310451/why-doesnt-scalas-implicit-class-work-when-one-of-the-type-parameters-should-b (and links to issues at scala bug tracker there)

Comment: By the way in Dotty the code compiles https://scastie.scala-lang.org/C8o3hD50RSKYYrBghbgdKw

Comment: Thanks for the links, these helped me find [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/73791p/nothings_twin_brother_the_better_one/) which I think is my preferred work around

Comment: I'm going to write this up as an answer for completeness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Dmytro's comment, I was able to find [this post suggesting a workaround](https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/73791p/nothings_twin_brother_the_better_one/) for this [bug](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/1570).

In short, we can define a type alias `Empty.T` for subtypes of `Nothing`

```scala
object Empty{
  type T <: Nothing
}
```

Since `Nothing` has no values, and no subtypes, `Empty.T` will also have no values. This lets us write our Absurd instances:

```scala
object Absurd {
  def apply[A: Absurd, B](a: A):B = implicitly[Absurd[A]].absurd[B](a)

  implicit val absurdForEmptyT: Absurd[Empty.T] = new Absurd[Empty.T]{
    override def absurd[X](a: Empty.T): X = a
  }

  implicit def absurdForEither[A:Absurd, B: Absurd]: Absurd[Either[A, B]] = new Absurd[Either[A, B]]{
    override def absurd[X](a: Either[A,B]): X = a match {
      case Left(a) => Absurd[A,X](a)
      case Right(b) => Absurd[B, X](b)
    }
  }
}
```

This works! The following will compile:

```scala
implicitly[Absurd[Either[Empty.T, Empty.T]]]
```

as does:

```scala
implicitly[Absurd[Either[Nothing, Nothing]]]
```

---

Since I'm porting Haskell code, which doesn't have to worry about variance, it would be equally valid to define our own empty type as a workaround:

```scala
sealed trait Empty

object Absurd {
  def apply[A: Absurd, B](a: A):B = implicitly[Absurd[A]].absurd[B](a)

  implicit val absurdForEmpty: Absurd[Empty] = new Absurd[Empty]{
    override def absurd[X](a: Empty): X = ???
  }
  // ...
}
```

This works, but personally I prefer the first approach, since it doesn't ignore the Empty type `Nothing` that's already built into Scala, and since It doesn't rely on us to use `???` to write the initial `Absurd[Empty]` instance.

Comment: Not only `implicitly[Absurd[Either[Empty.T, Empty.T]]]` compiles but also original `implicitly[Absurd[Either[Nothing, Nothing]]]`.

Comment: The benefit of this trick is that compiler knows that `Empty.T` is `Nothing` (`implicitly[Empty.T =:= Nothing]`,
  `implicitly[Nothing =:= Empty.T]` compile). Just compiler is less afraid of inferring `Empty.T` than `Nothing` itself.